# Emulator error in starting Androir Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio

I am new with Android Studio (3.0.1) so the first thing i did was creating a new virtual device.
After that, i tried running an app with my new virtual device but it gives me this error :

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1.
 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Can someone tell me what is needed?

Comment: Yes. The log already tells you it "requires hardware acceleration".

Comment: Totally. Meaning what exactly?

Comment: Enable CPU virtualization (for example VT-x), install HAXM, etc.

Comment: Can you provide the exact steps? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try another version of android studio, maybe your hardware can’t support 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on 3.0.1 , i've switched to 3.2.0 and it worked.